# CI multiple database connection with different server

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

i have an application which need to be connected to 2 different db and in different server. is there any other settings i have to do beside doing it in in database.php? i wrote this in my code to connect to both db:

```
$provinsi_db = $this->load->database('provinsi', true); //this is from another server
$local = $this->load->database('default', true); //this one is in my localhost
```

but when i tried to select data from the server db,, nothing happened.. there is no problem selecting data from local db though.. Can anyone help me?

Here is my database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username_local';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password_local';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_local';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['provinsi']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
$db['provinsi']['username'] = 'username_foreign';
$db['provinsi']['password'] = 'password_foreign';
$db['provinsi']['database'] = 'db_foreign';
$db['provinsi']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['provinsi']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['provinsi']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['provinsi']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['provinsi']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['provinsi']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['provinsi']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['provinsi']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['provinsi']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['provinsi']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['provinsi']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

do i have to include port in the server's 'hostname'?

Comment: did you set both configs for db in `database.php`? Can you show us your `database.php` also?

Comment: yes, i have, i've just include it now.. i don't think anything's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My whole database setup sample

// My database.php

```
/* API Database Connection */

$active_group = 'apidb';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['apidb']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['apidb']['username'] = 'user_name';
$db['apidb']['password'] = 'pass_word';
$db['apidb']['database'] = 'db_name';
$db['apidb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['apidb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['apidb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['apidb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['apidb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['apidb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['apidb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['apidb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['apidb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['apidb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['apidb']['stricton'] = FALSE;


/* Site Database Connection */

$active_group = 'sitedb';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['sitedb']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['sitedb']['username'] = 'user_name';
$db['sitedb']['password'] = 'pass_word';
$db['sitedb']['database'] = 'db_name';
$db['sitedb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['sitedb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['sitedb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['sitedb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['sitedb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['sitedb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['sitedb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['sitedb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['sitedb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['sitedb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['sitedb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

In controller, loading database

```
$this->sitedb = $this->load->database('sitedb', TRUE);
$this->apidb = $this->load->database('apidb', TRUE);
```

In model, you can call

```
$this->apidb->query('your query');
```

or

```
$this->sitedb->query('your query');
```

Comment: it works!! thank you. i am actually new in php and CI, so thank you very much :)

Comment: I also got the sample problem with two databases if each database the same server host it work fine but each one difference it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this in your config database.php

```
$db['provinsi']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: i have tried it,, but still doesn't work.. i don't know what's wrong